# How to substitute a pattern with another pattern in unix enviroment maintianing its values using sed/awk/tr?

Tags: unix, awk, sed, tr

I have this following data set in one file (.txt file)

data1 = 275736 490;data11 = 87551 1004; data2 = 344670 4875; data3 = 472996 840;data4  = 0 0;data = 19708 279;data6 = 10262 18;data7 = 0 0;data8 = 428 6;data9 = 5986 11;data10 = 15114 173;data11 = 7483 106;data = 15900 25;

I want replace this **digit space digit** pattern (for example **472996 840**) to **digit,digit** pattern (**472996,840**). This has to be done for **0 0** also as **0,0**. values shouldn't be changed. I cannot replace all white space since other whitespace are needed as well. I have to replace white space between the digits to another string.

Any suggestions using tr/sed/awk ?

Tried this :

```
sed -i 's/\d+\s\d+/\d+\d+/g' comment3.txt
```

Also, in tr looks like we cannot match a pattern

Comment: please do add your efforts(in form of code) in your question which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: `sed -E 's/([0-9])[ ]([0-9])/\1,\2/g' file` then add `-i` when satisfied it does what you intend.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info for learning resources

Comment: Indeed, `tr` is wholly unsuitable for this. I (finally) updated [the `tr` tag info page](/tags/tr/info) with a note about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way is to capture the digit before the space and the digit that follows it, then reinsert the digits with a comma in between using the first and second backreference `\1` and `\2`. You would use the normal substitution form of `sed 's/find/replace/'` adding `g` to make the replacements global (replace all). For example:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9])[ ]([0-9])/\1,\2/g' file
```

That will take your data, e.g.

```
data1 = 275736 490;data11 = 87551 1004; data2 = 344670 4875; data3 = 472996 840;...
```

and convert the line to:

```
data1 = 275736,490;data11 = 87551,1004; data2 = 344670,4875; data3 = 472996,840;...
```

You can add the `-i` to "edit-in-place" when you are satisfied it does what you intend.

Comment: sed -E 's/([0-9])[ ]([0-9])/\1,\2/g' file
So  here \1 and \2 in 'replace' section refers to matching sub expression of 'find' section right ?

Comment: Correct, each capture group `(...)` will capture what is between the parentheses and `\1` reinserts the information from the first group, `\2` from the second, and so on. If you did not have extended regular expressions available for your `sed` you would escape the capture groups using Basic Regular Expressions, e.g. `sed 's/\([0-9]\)[ ]\([0-9]\)/\1,\2/g' file` (it just looks busier, but does the exact same thing)

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** With GNU `awk`'s `gensub` function please try following.

```
awk '
{
  print gensub(/([0-9]+) +([0-9]+)/, "\\1,\\2", "g", $0)
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With GNU `awk`, you could try following too.

```
awk -v RS='[0-9]+[[:space:]]+[0-9]+' '{sub(/[[:space:]]+/,",",RT);ORS=RT} 1' Input_file
```